# sencha touch -- select field in a popup

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, extjs6-modern

I'm trying to create a very simple popup with a selectfield that prompts a user to, for example, select a region before the app launches.

However, I am facing three issues:

a) the dropdown list is shown behind the mask, even though I've configured

```
modal:false
```

so you can't make a selection until you close the prompt

b) there is no trigger button

c) and the default value is not selected even though I have added the `value` config

I am using the Ext 6.0.2 with the modern toolkit.

[here](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/1nt3) is the fiddle

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- First thing you should do to make sure the issue is not a buggy theme (yes, the Windows theme can be considered buggy! Test the date picker in a recent firefox, for example!) is to use the default for your framework version, which for 6.x is Triton. In this case, it's not the theme that's the issue.
- Second thing you should do to make sure you are not encountering an already fixed ExtJS code bug is to crosscheck your code with the newest framework version. Your code works fine in ExtJS 6.2.1 Triton, so it's a bug in the 6.0.2 framework.
  (Before you ask: the "Windows" theme has been deprecated in 6.2.x, by the way)

Comment: just upgraded to 6.2.0, everything is working fine now.